# Acpi shows 2 batteries but the laptop has only one

Tags: battery, acpi

I've an ASUS F522L laptop and Kubuntu 20.04 with 5.4.0-65-generic kernel
The battery indicator works fine (charging/discharging/percentage) but the command
`acpi -V` gives to me this output:

```
Battery 0: Charging, 99%, 00:01:32 until charged
Battery 0: design capacity 2600 mAh, last full capacity 2282 mAh = 87%
Battery 1: Discharging, 0%, rate information unavailable
```

Why does it return to me 2 batteries even if there is only one ?
In `/sys/class/power_supply` directory I've only `BAT0`

Thanks.

### Further info:

After a while I executed the same command and I got this result:

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 0%, rate information unavailable
Battery 1: Not charging, 100%
Battery 1: design capacity 2600 mAh, last full capacity 1870 mAh = 71%
```

NOw it seems that the correct results are the ones of "Battery 1" but in `/sys/class/power_supply` directory there is still only `BAT0` with the same values shown by acpi -v

Comment: Maybe you have any wireless mouse/keyboard connected.

Comment: Yes @hellking ,  you are right. I had a wireless mouse and I verified that it is the source of the BAT1 value. Thank you very much.